# Get custom meta all users Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I did make a custom field to users profile and I'm trying to retrieve all the users custom meta in array but i'm getting an error:

```
$users = get_users(array(
'meta_key'     => 'phone'));
foreach ($users as  $value) {
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $value->ID );

$merged_array=array();
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($all_meta_for_user as $meta) {
   $result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $meta);
}
var_export($result);exit;
}
```

Comment: Please clearly define your problem instead of just saying "I'm getting an error." What have you tried?

Comment: Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in E:\Server\www\wp\wp-content\plugins\mohamedsaleh\layout\send.php on line 11

thats the error

Comment: Your problem is stated in the error you got. `array_merge` requires that the parameter passed be an array. Clearly, `$meta` is not an an array.

Comment: it's a array i'm sure i did var_dump it  i did try many ways to get all user custom meta but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

her is the Solution

```
 $users = get_users(); 
$users_array = array();
foreach ($users as $user) { 
$t =get_the_author_meta( 'phone' , $user->ID );
if (strlen($t) >= 12 && strlen($t) <= 14 ) {
   $users_array[]=$t;
}

} 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($users_array);
echo "</pre>";
```